# How do I overwrite a file if it already exists?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text-files, streamwriter

I'm making a text editor using fastColoredTextbox. I have a button that allows you to save your text onto your pc. The problem is that it throws an exception when the user tries to save the file as a file that already exists, instead of overwriting the file.

This is my code.

```js
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt|*.txt|All files|*.*";
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
    {
        sw.Write(fastColoredTextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

How would I go about making it overwrite the file if it already exists?

Comment: just use File.WriteAllText  if file not exists will be created if exists will be overwriten

Comment: That's what you asked for, use FileMode.Create instead.

Comment: How about `FileMode.Truncate` or `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed up my code a bit and ended up going with this, which somehow got it to work.

```js
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt|*.txt|All files|*.*";
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Stream s = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
    sw.Write(fastColoredTextBox1.Text);
    sw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

```
sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
sw.WriteLine(line);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)